# php - how to convert 'tree-array' to array

Tags: php

I have gotten the `tree-array` like that:

[image]

Now I want to convert it to an array like this:

```
array(
      1 => array('id'=>'1','parentid'=>0),
      2 => array('id'=>'2','parentid'=>0),
      3 => array('id'=>'3','parentid'=>1),
      4 => array('id'=>'4','parentid'=>1),
      5 => array('id'=>'5','parentid'=>2),
      6 => array('id'=>'6','parentid'=>3),
      7 => array('id'=>'7','parentid'=>3)
      );
```

I had already coded something like this:

```
private function _getOrderData($datas)
{
    $_data = [];
    static $i = 0;
    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $i++;
        $rows = ['id' => $data['id'], 'pid' => isset($data['children']) ? $data['id'] : 0, 'menu_order' => $i];
        if(isset($data['children'])) {
            $this->_getOrderData($data['children']);
        }
        $_data[] = $rows;
    }
    return $_data;
}
```

But it didn't work

Cry~~

How can I fix my code to get the array? Thanks~

BTW, my English is pool.

So much as I don't know you can read my description of the problem or not.

Comment: . post your sample array instead of image

Comment: We need your actual array and also explain which is `children` and `parent` from your actual array..

Answer (score 1):

I had already solved this problem, Thx~

```
private function _getOrderData($datas, $parentid = 0)
{
    $array = [];
    foreach ($datas as $val) {
        $indata = array("id" => $val["id"], "parentid" => $parentid);
        $array[] = $indata;
        if (isset($val["children"])) {
            $children = $this->_getOrderData($val["children"], $val["id"]);
            if ($children) {
                $array = array_merge($array, $children);
            }
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

The array look like:
[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIors.png)